# How do I input the same text in more than one windows simultaneously?

Tags: input

How do I input the same text in more than one windows simultaneously in linux like to chrome and firefox at a time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [xlax](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/xlax/xlax.1.en.html) here.

This is the program specifically designed to mirror keyboard input to different windows of X-server.

Comment: it's not working on ubuntu bionic...```Segmentation fault (core dumped)```

Comment: any alternatives to xlax?

Comment: May be you hit some bug. On ubuntu focal in KDE it mostly works (although backspace does not work in kate).